# When should I create a new window instead of using many different views?

Tags: cocoa-touch

You create a window, and inside the window you create many views, but how many windows do you create per app?

Say you have a login screen, a register form screen, and a dashboard screen.

So do you create:

1. One window and many views for the login and register screens and one window for  the dashboard?
2. One login window with login view, one Register window (with Register screen view 1, register screen view 2, and register screen view 3), and one dashboard window (with many views)?

Furthermore, do you always need a view? If it's just one screen, can't you just create one window and add buttons, labels, and other things?

EDIT: according to apple... its 1 controller 1 view? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CombiningViewControllers/CombiningViewControllers.html

Answer (score 2):

The convention is to have only one Window which is declared in your `AppDelegate`. Inside of windows you add ViewControllers which can handle all your additional views. So you'd create a `LoginViewController` and a `RegisterViewController`.

Usually multiple windows are only needed for things like creating an alert (UIAlertView is its own UIWindow) that would be on top of all other views, but even this can be achieved by using `keyWindow`.

Comment: There are reasons to add new windows too, however. Alerts, notifications, etc. are implemented with windows.

Comment: How about a twitter-style overlay, auto-dismissing alert (e.g. "Sent"), like Xcode's "Build Succeeded" (semitransparent black round-rect with white text and icon)? I guess you can do it _without_ a new window as long as you can ensure that the alert view stays on the absolute top (above rootViewController's view)

Comment: ...but using a different window saves you the trouble of ensuring that, especially if the navigation is quite complex.

Comment: What about create a windows for each group of views? Settings its own windows with many views, account profile its own windows with many views?

Comment: Answer found http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Understanding_iPhone_Views,_Windows_and_the_View_Hierarchy

Comment: what about this? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CombiningViewControllers/CombiningViewControllers.html

Comment: Like I said in my answer, if you need something to be on top of all other views, I think a window would definitely be best, but you can always use [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow. I think the techtopia answer that @001 found is correct and an extension of what I said.

Comment: Can I have two windows? one for when login screen, the other for dashboard screen? or its always better to just have 1 window with many views? :/